# How to get agitator off for this Frigidaire washer?

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have seen plenty of youtube videos on how to release the agitator from rest of washing machine. Seems easy.

However, for my FEX831FS4 washer the bolt is kinda surrounded by the agitator's plastic housing and the only way I **may** be able to unscrew that nut would be with a very deep, thin walled socket. Wrench does not bite the nut enough and regular socket can't get on top of nut because the protruding thread is very high. See this picture to understand what I mean

[image]

This has made me wondering If I am doing things the right way to fix the broken agitator? Wanted to hear from someone who has worked on washers before whether

1. I need to start disassembly from bottom for this washer and not top to release the agitator?
2. When the agitator got broken perhaps it was pushed upwards (or downwards) over bolt and I now simply need to use some force?
3. I simply need a special, deep socket with thin walls to unscrew that nut?

Any thoughts? [Here](https://www.partswarehouse.com/Frigidaire-FEX831FS4-Washer-Dryer-Combo-s/70206.htm) is parts schematics. If I understand correctly then last picture of transmission shows that bolt. But then it seems that the plastic agitator should simply come after unscrewing the plastic cap without having me to unscrew this bolt. Which does not seem to be the case.

Comment: I've not worked on this specific model, but with a similar one I recall that the agitator just pulls off once you remove the cap.  They get gummed up with detergent residue so it takes some force to get it started.

Comment: @jwh20 You were right agitator just pulled off. Can you post that as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sure can and glad to have been able to help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've not worked on this specific model, but with a similar one I recall that the agitator just pulls off once you remove the cap.

They get gummed up with detergent residue so it takes some force to get it started.